# Deep learning classification with multiple temporal data

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, classification, unsupervised-learning, data-preprocessing

I'm working on a project to predict the category of music segments in an audio file (represented in pianoroll format with an additional column for the corresponding class). Each row represents the state of the notes after 50ms, and the last column is the class into which this state was labelled. I've got 150 such music files that are labelled and want to train a supervised model to be able to classify new music into segments. However, I have multiple problems:

1. the problem of temporal dependence. The commonly used algorithms work with spatial data as far as I'm concerned. So how should one capture the temporal aspect?
2. the problem of data representation. How can I train a method on 80% of my 150 files and test on the remaining 20%? The states of one matrix are dependent on one another, but concatenating the matrices of the 150 files is a bit much. Plus 2 matrices are different in length, and have no musical connection to one another in any way.

I cannot come up with a method to train one network on multiple files, nor how to capture the temporal aspect of this task. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: If you have class labels, how is this an unsupervised task?

Answer (score 1):

1. [rnn](/questions/tagged/rnn), [gru](/questions/tagged/gru) and [lstm](/questions/tagged/lstm) are all common choices for modeling sequential data using neural networks.
2. If you have 150 songs, and you want to measure how well your model generalizes to *new* songs, you hold out some portion (you mentioned 20%) of the 150 songs. Sequences of different lengths can be padded and masked. There are standard methods to do this in widely-used NN libraries (Tensorflow, Torch, etc.). An example is [`TORCH.NN.UTILS.RNN.PACK_PADDED_SEQUENCE`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence.html)
   .